# How do i assign a static IP for windows PC?

Tags: networking

I am new to a small firm that only has a few of us in this small office. When I check the desktop PC network settings, I notice that 3 desktop PC here have static IP in their IPv4 Network Settings set.

I tried logging into router portal page, I dont see any page where I can reserve static IP.

Since I don't have a very strong networking background, how do I set a new laptop to have static IP? I can think of 2 methods, so kindly enlighten me which is true:

**Method A:**

Connect to the router via wifi/cable. It will be assigned with a dynamic IP by default.
Jot down the IP that is assigned and put that into IPv4 settings and set as static IP.

**Method B**

Access to router portal. Find a place where it will generate a static IP.
Put that static IP to the windows PC IPv4 settings.
May I know which is the correct method for setting new static Ip for new PC?

You might have question to me asking the reason behind static IP purpose. I can only tell you that I am in the midst of understanding it as well as I am new to this firm and there is no IT people here.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the router, there should be an option to tie your PC's MAC to a static IP.

Before that, on the router page, look for a list of devices on the network - along with their IPs and MAC addresses, recognize your PC's MAC or current IP (check it by typing ipconfig in terminal on Windows), then copy the MAC address.

Then, go to Reserved IP/ Static IP settings and add an entry there.

There you will type in that MAC address and an IP of your choice (that's available, in the /24 range). This will tell the router to always give that same IP to your PC which is identified with a MAC address.

I don't know the router model, but I'm pretty sure all of them have some sort of IP assign option. On the off chance that it's some odd router and it does not have it, you're out of luck since you can not force DHCP to deal specific IP addresses otherwise.

Edit: as for your methods,

A) you could do that but it might not be permanent. If you set the Static IP settings on your PC, it will only ask for that IP, it's not guaranteed it will get it (since the router is on DHCP and you didn't reserve that address). It will work in the start, but if you turn off your PC, and someone else joins the network, there is a chance they will get your IP, and you will get a new one when you turn the PC back on.

As for B) Yeah something like that will work, but it works a bit differently, as I explained above

Comment: Hi @math101 , my router is D-Link DIR-850L. I tried browsing some of the pages in router portal but i coudn't find a page that allows or shows the list of reserve IP and MAC. Are you familiar with how this particular router portal works?

Comment: Guide from the manual page of the router: Go to Settings tab, and then Network. You should get [this](https://i.imgur.com/Gaf49tE.png) . Then go to Connected clients, and you should be get a list of connected PCs. Find your PC in that list, and click the edit (pencil) button like [here](https://i.imgur.com/TFkt2Iv.png). Finally, you will get a chance to type in the IP you want, and turn on the reserved option to make it static, as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/HoAs8K6.png) .

Comment: thanks for your guide. 

I noticed that none of the connected devices have reserved IP. However, I notice the pattern in such a way:
Desktop PC and Printers that have static IP (In Windows settings) is always 192.168.0.2XX
Whereas laptop and handphone IP is always 192.168.0.1XX


So does that mean the previous guy who configure for me randomly put in a larger number as static IP? 

If this is the case, as we have more and more new PC (with dynamic IP), eventually IP will hit 192.168.0.2XX and causing IP clash with static PC ?

Comment: If there are no static IPs set on the router, the router gives out IP in order up to 192.168.0.254. When we set a static IP on Windows (but not on the router), all we are doing is requesting a specific IP. If it is available (no one is using it), the router doesn't care and gives it to you. That can work, but if someone (eg. while that PC is off) gets on the network and accidentally(or by requesting it) receives your IP, you can't have it until that other PC releases it.

Comment: About the IP conflicts, the fact that static IPs are in 200 range is just a coincidence, or the tech guy just likes it there for better organisation. You can set any IP as static. Since, once a computer turns off, the router takes it's IP and makes it free for others to use, reaching the 200 mark would mean that there are 200 devices online. If some IPs over 200 are in use/static(windows side) the router will skip them and pick the first available one after that and assign it to a new device. If there are none left(eg. 200 dynamic and 54 static) the network is full.

Answer (score 0):

Basic SoHo routers that don’t offer you static IPv4 address assignment may be smart enough to only use part of LAN subnet for dhcp allocations allowing you to pick addressees from the remainder for static allocation.

For instance on a 192.168.10.0/24 subnet the DHCP server may be using 192.168.10.128 - 192.168.10.254 and when you select an IP between 2 and 127 for static assignments (assuming that the router uses 192.168.10.1 ) you won’t end up with conflicts.

Another possibility: your predecessor simply set static addresses without thinking about possible consequences ,because  as longs as everything in your network uses unique static IPv4 addresses and ignores dhcp , that won’t break anything either.

But in the long run static IPv4 addresses will cost you too much manual overhead without any benefit